# Why my Nested Stack goes to the first screen, despite what the docs says React Navigation, React Native - ANSWER INSIDE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

ANSWER: you should do inside the Stack.Screen of the nested Navigator `options={{headerShown:false}}`

like this:

```
<Stack.Screen name="NestedNav" component={Nested_Navigator} options={{headerShown: false}} />
```

I started learning React-Native, I was reading the docs, and it sent me to React-Navigation docs.
according to the docs if I have `Nested navigators` each navigator stack will have it's own stack history,

from the docs:

```
"For example, when you press the back button inside a nested stack navigator,
 it'll go back to the previous screen inside the nested stack even if there's 
another navigator as the parent."
```

I have a nested stack navigator, but two things happen, the first (when inside the parent I only have the screen that has the nested navigator), is the I don't get the default back button.
the second, if I display the screen with the nested stack navigators, I do get the back button, but it returns to the first screen. (where I call the nested navigators from)

my code:  this is the very first screen of the app
e

```
xport default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{  headerStyle: {backgroundColor:'#f4511e'}, headerTintColor:'#fff',headerTitleStyle:{fontWeight:'bold'},headerTitleAlign:'center' , headerBackTitleVisible:false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={({navigtion, route}) => ({headerTitle: props=><Screen_Image_Header/> }) } initialParams={{ownTitle: "MY DAMNED TITLE"}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} options={{ title:"" }}  />
        <Stack.Screen name="CreatePost" component={CreatePostScreen} options={ ({route}) => ({title: route.params.name}) }/>
        <Stack.Screen name="NestedNav" component={Nested_Navigator} /> -- this is the screen with nested nav
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

the nested nav screen code:

```
const Tab = createStackNavigator();

export default function Nested_Navigator() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed">
            <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed_Nest_Tab} options={{ title: "Hello" }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages_Nest_Tab} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

the Home screen (the first to be displayed):

```
export default function HomeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
 return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(ownTitle)}</Text>
        <Button title="Go To Details" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', { itemId: 86, otherParam: 'just some other param' })} />
        <Button title="Create Post" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreatePost', { name: "Are Ya winning song?" })} />
        <Button title="Update the Screen Title" onPress={() => navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Updated!' })} />
        <Button title="Go to Nestned Stack" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('NestedNav')} />
        <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>Post: {route.params?.post}</Text>
        <Text>Count: {count}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

}

the two nested Screens:

```
export default function Feed_Nest_Tab({route, navigation}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello From Feed Tab</Text>
            <Button title="Go to messages" onPress={()=> (navigation.navigate('Messages')) } />
        </View>
    )
}

export default function Messages_Nest_Tab({route, navigation}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello from Messages Tab</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

the docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Already published an issue on their Github https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8733

Comment: @Tupini I managed to fix it, it's happening because the header of the first navigation is on top of the nested one. to fix it, type it like this:  `<Stack.Screen name="NestedNav" component={Nested_Navigator} options={{headerShown: false}} />`

Comment: Thank you @pythwan. It helped me a lot. I already closed the issue on Github. You should do the same here and provide an answer for future people who has the same issue. :)

Comment: @Tupini I once did that and some people downvoted my question to -3, but will edit, and may god be with me in this community.